# Does JHipster support the Keycloak client resource authorization configuration?

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I have a JHipster Gateway and Microservice that are currently configured to use OAUTH/OIDC via Keycloak.  Currently all resources are available to the authenticated user.  I want to use the fine-grained security available in keycloak (enabling authorization on the JHipster Microservice client id) to further secure by resource id (as referenced in Keycloak documentation)
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_resource_server_enable_authorization.  For example, restrict */api/companies/{id} to only certain Keycloak users/groups.

It this supported in Jhipster?  Based on the logs, it looks like AccessControlFilter can be configured to restrict, but It's not clear to me how this connects to Keycloak fine-grained resource authentication.

```
2018-04-15 07:11:20.905 DEBUG 18184 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.e.gateway.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Enter: com.example.gateway.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount() with argument[s] = [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@2ea9380c: Principal: user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: company.jcb.role1, ROLE_USER]
2018-04-15 07:11:20.907 DEBUG 18184 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.e.gateway.aop.logging.LoggingAspect    : Exit: com.example.gateway.web.rest.AccountResource.getAccount() with result = com.example.gateway.domain.User@3a45e83a
2018-04-15 07:11:22.208 DEBUG 18184 --- [oundChannel-104] c.e.g.web.websocket.ActivityService      : Sending user tracking data ActivityDTO{sessionId='hchu0fkx', userLogin='user', ipAddress='/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54212', page='/', time='2018-04-15T13:11:22.208Z'}
2018-04-15 07:11:24.634 DEBUG 18184 --- [ XNIO-2 task-19] c.e.g.g.a.AccessControlFilter            : Access Control: allowing access for /micro/api/companies, as no access control policy has been set up for service: micro
```

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't define realm roles as we do in jhipster-realm.json ?

Comment: I could do something like that if necessary, but I was hoping to leverage the keycloak resource authorization solution so I wouldn't need to write the security management inside the application.  Would an AccessControlFilter or extending ZuulFilter be another option to call KeyCloak and still play nicely with the existing Keycloak OAUTH integration?

Comment: I don't know. You've decided to use a Keycloak specific feature while JHipster's approach is to build something that could apply to several identity providers like Keycloak and Okta and potentially others. If you think this is generic enough you can propose and contribute an enhancement request on github

Answer (score 0):

Since the Keycloak Resource Server authorization as described in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_resource_server_enable_authorization was not supported by Jhipster, to secure resources more granularly I decided to:

- Upon creation of a resource I want to secure in the microservice, I dynamically create Keycloak group hierarchies via the Keycloak API.  For example, if I want to secure access to companies 123 and 456 and I have roles: Account Manager,Employee, Supervisor I create the Keycloak group hierarchies

> ```
> 123
> - Account Manager
> - Employee
> - Supervisor  
>
> 456
> - Account Manager
> - Employee
> - Supervisor
> ```

User accounts can be assigned to the various groups.  For example, user "John" might have access to company "456" and role "Employee"

- Added the group hierarchies as a claim to the JWT token via the Keycloak Mappers (this was a configuration in the Keycloak client configuration/Mappers )
- In the microservice, use the added JWT group claim for any queries accessing resources that are restricted.